# Dynamic hotkeys for Visual Studio extension

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

Is there any way I can dynamically add global hotkeys from within a Visual Studio extension / package?

Declaring the hotkeys in the *.vsct file of my package is no option because I do not know which hotkeys should be available at runtime - there is kind of a plugin-system within my extension that can add/remove hotkeys dynamically.

Adding a message filter does only work when .NET runs the message loop - which is not the case in VS.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to add hot keys is to go ahead and define your commands without any key bindings.  Essentially make sure that the command `MyExtension.MyOperation` is available but bound to no keys.

At run time you can grab the `DTE.Command` object for your extension command.  It's available through the `Commands` property on the `DTE` object.  From there you can change the key the particular command is bound to by setting the `Binding` property.

For example if you wanted to change the binding to <kbd>CTRL+o</kbd> I would do the following

```
command.Binding = "Global::ctrl+o";
```

The syntax for the key binding is actually fairly well documented on MSDN.

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.command.bindings(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.command.bindings%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jared, the problem is that I do not even know which commands will be available because the plugins will provide them. My last resort would be to define a fixed number of dummy commands for which the plugins can register themselves. But this does seem totally mad to me.